# how to write to a text file using to log4j?

Tags: java, logging, file, log4j

I'm wondering how to convert the following code to output those lines into a text file, and not to standard output:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger; import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class HelloWorld {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
        logger.debug("Sample debug message");
        logger.info("Sample info message");
        logger.warn("Sample warn message");
        logger.error("Sample error message");
        logger.fatal("Sample fatal message");
    }
}
```

The properties file is :

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is in your log4j.properties file?

Comment: edited the message , check it out

Comment: Many webservers (Jetty, for example) redirect stdout to a file, so depending you may not even need to worry about this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Change the ConsoleAppender to a FileAppender.

I find the `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`
to be useful.
If you use this,
you must add a property for the fileName and
may want to set the maxFileSize as well.
Here is an example (put these in the log4j.properties file):

```
log4j.appender.NotConsole=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.NotConsole.fileName=/some/path/to/a/fileName.log
log4j.appender.NotConsole.maxFileSize=20MB
```

There are other appenders.
`DailyRollingFileAppender` rolls based on time.
`FileAppender` does not roll.
If you use the `RollingFileAppender`,
you will need to guess as to a good value for maxFileSize and
then address the size at a future date if it is causing issues.

Comment: what if i dont know the bound of the file size before runtime?

Comment: Thanks , but is it possible to change this size according to an input in runtime?  My input is a program , and the more time it run, the larger the output file is.

Comment: You can configure you appender at runtime.  I use the Log4j PropertyConfigurator and pass to the static configure() method a properties object that I build at runtime.

Comment: How do I use your example? Where do I put the 3 lines of code?

Comment: The lines I show above go in the log4j.properties configuration file.

Comment: @DwB, do you know how to provide a relative path? E.g. my java jar will be run on different machine, how I can specify to write into the current folder where the jar is run. e.g. into folder ~/CurrentFolder/filename.log ?

Comment: @DwB, following your advice, I put a path to a text file, but when running the java program, the following error happens: 
`log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.`
`java.io.FileNotFoundException:` `"C:\Xiang\codes\Java_dev\HDFSOperation\hdfslog.txt" `
`(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`
`at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)`

Comment: Read the error message.  It says that something is wrong in the path and/or the file name.  do you have a directory named Java_dev or is it named Java.dev?

Answer (score 8):

Shortly use FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender.

Here is a simple example of configuration. It additionally configures the layout. You can omit it for the first approach.

```
log4j.appender.F=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.F.File=mylog.log
log4j.appender.F.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.F.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd@HH:mm:ss} %-5p (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n
```

Comment: where do i choose the file i want to use? with getlogger?

Answer (score 4):

The following would be helpful:

**Class containing main method**

```
    package abc;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

    public class ClassOne {
        static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClassOne.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.info"); //log4j.info file should be in the class path(same location as ClassOne.class)

             logger.info("Program started.... "); //Whenever you want to write something to the log text file use logger.info("Log Message")

        }
    }
```

**log4j.info file**

```
   log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE

   # Define the file appender
   log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender // Replacing ConsoleAppender with FileAppender gives text file logging

   # Set the name of the file
   log4j.appender.FILE.File=src/abc/log.out //Here you can specify either absolute or relative path

   # Set the immediate flush to true (default)
   log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

   # Set the threshold to debug mode
   log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

   # Set the append to false, overwrite
   log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

   # Define the layout for file appender
   log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d %m%n
```

Answer (score 1):

following configuration should aslo work

### direct log messages to stdout ###

> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
>   log4j.appender.stdout.fileName=error.log
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p
>   %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Answer (score 0):

**in log4j.properties**

```
# Define the root logger with file appender
log4j.logger.App = DEBUG ,CA

#set file text
log4j.appender.CA = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CA.File = D:\\database.log
log4j.appender.CA.maxFileSize = 20MB
log4j.appender.CA.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```