# Log4j: How to configure simplest possible file logging?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

**My story:**

I want to make a thing which is as simple as a  simplest possible log4j logger that logs rows to a file. I have found several examples with some functionality, but not a basic, general one that really works, and not one with an explanation how the each row work.

**Question:**

Could anybody provide one?

**Prerequisites:**

> - I already know where to put the file and I have the log4j configured and working for console logging.
> - Now I want to log to a file and also find the file from file system once the program has run.
> - Rows needed to be added to the existing `log4j.properties` file are the desired output.

Comment: Here's an older question on the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474646/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-using-to-log4j

Comment: This is first time I configure a file appender to my project. What permissions should be given so that the logging really goes to the file. I hardly remember something from past that at least file permissions to the file should be fixed and probably some other program related permissions. I'm making this in Linux.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I have one generic log4j.xml file for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration debug="false">

    <appender name="default.console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="target" value="System.out" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="default.file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="/log/mylogfile.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="another.file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="/log/anotherlogfile.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.yourcompany.SomeClass" additivity="false">
        <level value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="another.file" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="default.console" />
        <appender-ref ref="default.file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

with one console, two file appender and one logger poiting to the second file appender instead of the first.

**EDIT**

In one of the older projects I have found a simple log4j.properties file:

```
# For the general syntax of property based configuration files see
# the documentation of org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.

# The root category uses two appenders: default.out and default.file.
# The first one gathers all log output, the latter only starting with 
# the priority INFO.
# The root priority is DEBUG, so that all classes can be logged unless 
# defined otherwise in more specific properties.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, default.out, default.file

# System.out.println appender for all classes
log4j.appender.default.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.default.out.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.default.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.default.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.file=/log/mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.default.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c: %m%n
```

For the description of all the layout arguments look here: [log4j PatternLayout arguments](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

Comment: I asked also for explanations. What does layout parameters on `default-file` appender do, for example? I could use that but don't understand that part.

Comment: it is an output pattern, those % placeholders decide what information gets logged and how to format those, look at the link I'll add in a moment to the answer

Comment: I have almost similar log4j.xml but still i am only getting the logs in console only and not written to the file, though the log file is getting generated. Just wanted to ask what all dependencies and jars to be added here. I believe I have some conflicting jars in my classapth. Moreover what to have in the level so as to get all type of logs i.e. info, error, debug etc?

Comment: In my case I had only to have log4j.jar in the class path. Unless you are using facades between your code and log4j or custom appenders it should be enough. Then set the level of the logger pointing to your code path to something verbose, like `debug`, `trace` or even `all`. And set `threshold` param of the file appender to the same value.

Answer (score 33):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

   <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
      <param name="File" value="sample.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
      </layout>
   </appender>

  <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" /> 
  </root> 

</log4j:configuration>
```

Log4j can be a bit confusing. So lets try to understand what is going on in this file:
In log4j you have two basic constructs appenders and loggers.

**Appenders** define how and where things are appended. Will it be logged to a file, to the console, to a database, etc.?  In this case you are specifying that log statements directed to fileAppender will be put in the file `sample.log` using the pattern specified in the **layout** tags. You could just as easily create a appender for the console or the database. Where the console appender would specify things like the layout on the screen and the database appender would have connection details and table names.

**Loggers** respond to logging events as they bubble up. If an event catches the interest of a specific logger it will invoke its attached appenders. In the example below you have only one logger the root logger - which responds to all logging events by default. In addition to the root logger you can specify more specific loggers that respond to events from specific packages. These loggers can have their own appenders specified using the `appender-ref` tags or will otherwise inherit the appenders from the root logger. Using more specific loggers allows you to fine tune the logging level on specific packages or to direct certain packages to other appenders.

So what this file is saying is:

1. Create a fileAppender that logs to
   file sample.log
2. Attach that appender to the root
   logger.
3. The root logger will respond to any
   events at least as detailed as
   'debug' level
4. The appender is configured to only
   log events that are at least as
   detailed as 'info'

The net out is that if you have a `logger.debug("blah blah")` in your code it will get ignored. A `logger.info("Blah blah");` will output to sample.log.

The snippet below could be added to the file above with the **log4j** tags. This logger would inherit the appenders from `<root>` but would limit the all logging events from the package `org.springframework` to those logged at level `info` or above.

```
  <!-- Example Package level Logger -->
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="info"/>
    </logger>
```

Comment: where the file sample.log will be created?

Comment: I think that is a big depends. Outside a container I believe that this would put the log file in your `CWD`, but if you are configuring logging in a container, the container may put it somewhere else.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple one that I often use:

```
# Set up logging to include a file record of the output
# Note: the file is always created, even if there is 
# no actual output.
log4j.rootLogger=error, stdout, R

# Log format to standard out
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=   %5p\t[%d] [%t] (%F:%L)\n     \t%m%n\n

# File based log output
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=owls_conditions.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10000KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=   %5p\t[%d] [%t] (%F:%L)\n     \t%m%n\n
```

The format of the log is as follows:

```
ERROR   [2009-09-13 09:56:01,760] [main] (RDFDefaultErrorHandler.java:44)
        http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#(line 1 column 1): Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Such a format is defined by the string `%5p\t[%d] [%t] (%F:%L)\n     \t%m%n\n`. You can read the meaning of conversion characters in [log4j javadoc for `PatternLayout`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html).

Included comments should help in understanding what it does. Further notes:

- it logs both to console and to file; in this case the file is named `owls_conditions.log`: change it according to your needs;
- files are rotated when they reach 10000KB, and one back-up file is kept

Answer (score 3):

Here is a log4j.properties file that I've used with great success.

```
logDir=/var/log/myapp

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a}|%-5p|%-30c{1}| %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.stdout.File=${logDir}/myapp.log
log4j.appender.stdout.append=true
```

The DailyRollingFileAppender will create new files each day with file names that look like this:

```
myapp.log.2017-01-27
myapp.log.2017-01-28
myapp.log.2017-01-29
myapp.log  <-- today's log
```

Each entry in the log file will will have this format:

```
01/30/2017 12:59:47 AM|INFO |Component1   | calling foobar(): userId=123, returning totalSent=1
01/30/2017 12:59:47 AM|INFO |Component2   | count=1 > 0, calling fooBar()
```

Set the location of the above file by using `-Dlog4j.configuration`, as mentioned in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390521/change-location-of-log4j-properties):

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/myapp/config/log4j.properties com.foobar.myapp
```

In your Java code, be sure to set the name of each software component when you instantiate your logger object. I also like to log to both the log file and standard output, so I wrote this small function.

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("Component1");

public static void log(org.apache.log4j.Logger logger, String message) {

    logger.info(message);
    System.out.printf("%s\n", message);
}

public static String stackTraceToString(Exception ex) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    ex.printStackTrace(pw);
    return sw.toString();
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
LOGGER.info(String.format("Exception occurred: %s", stackTraceToString(ex)));
```