# hadoop override log4j.properties per job

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, log4j

Is it possible to override log4j properties per job?
I have a multi-step program (a pipeline) that runs some hadoop jobs 
 but before and after it also performs some other steps.

if I run my program using java command (`java -jar my_program.jar`)
then it runs OK but I get warning:
`Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

If I run my program using hadoop command (`hadoop jar my_program.jar`)
then default hadoop log4j.properties are loaded

In my program I log information about steps execution to a specific file. I do not need logs from hadoop map/reduce tasks. I need logs from my program because it performs many other tasks.

**Should I worry about that warning?

How to override log4j properties per job to keep logs from my pipeline with my custom log4j.properties?**

I am using hadoop v1.0.4

**EDIT:** 
I discovered that after exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the warning `Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform...` no longer appears when running my program with command `java -jar my_program.jar`. Source description: 
 
http://balanceandbreath.blogspot.ca/2013/01/utilnativecodeloader-unable-to-load.html 
 
**Does someone know how to How to override log4j properties per job?**

Comment: I found how to solve the warning - details in updated question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7390644/4496488 
I am using folowing code to load my custom `log4j.properties` in the main code that launches hadoop jobs (in this case it actually overwrites the hadoop log4j config):

```
String log4jPropertiesFilePath = "path/to/my/custom/log4j.properties";
PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jPropertiesFilePath);
```

It does not overwrite the log4j properties in datanodes - only in the program launching hadoop jobs - it is exactly what I wanted.