# slf4j over log4j configuration after deployment

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I have built a java application and I've been using slf4j/log4j for logging. I would now like to provide the user with the possibility of changing logging levels without needing to re build the .jar file.

I've read around that to do this your properties file needs to be inside of the classpath of the application. I've tried using the Class-Path header in the MANIFEST.MF file to achieve this, however it is not working.

These are the two examples I've tried.

```
Class-Path:./config/
Class-Path:C:/users/user/directory/tools/config/
```

However none of these seem to be added to the classpath as I've tried printing its contents once the application starts running.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390521/change-location-of-log4j-properties), I ended up adding a parameter to the java execution command. Bear in mind that if you execute through bash commands, as I do, you need to add the full path to the directory.

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties -jar myApp.jar
```

I don't like this since it makes it extremely dependent on path configuration but it will suffice.

Comment: Have a look to my updated answer. This might be a solution to prevent the hardcoded absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a list of possible solutions.

**1)** `java -jar myApp.jar` will search for the `log4j.properties` in following order

- root of `myApp.jar`
- the directories specified in the header `Class-Path:` of the `myApp.jar`

**2)** `java -Dlog4j.configuration=file://path/to/file//log4j.properties -jar myApp.jar` will use the properties file specified by `-Dlog4j.configuration=...`

**3)** `java -Xbootclasspath/a:../config -jar myApp.jar` will search for the `log4j.properties` in following order

- directory `../config/`
- root of `myApp.jar`
- the directories specified in the manifest header `Class-Path:` of the `myApp.jar`

I believe solution **1)** should solve your problem like following

- make sure there is no `log4j.configuration` in the root of `myApp.jar`
- the manifest header contina for example `Class-Path: config/`
- and the directory structure of your installation is
  ./myApp.jar
  ./config/

**edit** A possibe solution to avoid the hardcoded path, but  use a defined location for the `log4j.properties` file could be as below.

assume following structure of your application

```
c:\somewhere\myApp.jar
c:\somewhere\config\log4j.properties
c:\somewhere\run_myapp.cmd
```

**run_myapp.cmd**

```
@echo off
... do your necessary preparation here
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:%~dp0log4j_2.properties -jar myApp.jar
```

This will use always the `config\log4j.properties` relative to your `myApp.jar`.

`%~pd` - expands to drive letter and path of `run_myapp.cmd`

With this solution your users need to store the properties file at the given place but don't need to change the `run_myapp.cmd` script.