# Do I have to place log4j.properties in src/main/rescoures when I use maven?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, logging, log4j2

I have a web-API that deploys on a tomcat. I want to use log4j2 to print from the the API so I can track the calls that made to the API.

The war-file will be deployed on different machines with tomcat. I want to be able to place the log4j.properties file in a place where I don't overwrite it each time I make a new deploy.

As I've understood it the log4j.properties files should be placed in src/main/rescources when using maven (I am using maven). When I place the file in that folder I get log4j2 working. 
However if I make a new deploy the log4j.properties-file will be overwritten.

Is there anyway to place the log4j.propterties file outside that folder when I use Maven? Perhaps in the tomcat folder?

I've tried to make changes in the pom.xml. I tried to change the location in two places.

`<log4j.configuration>./conf/log4j.properties</log4j.configuration>`

And

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

I tried just changing the location in one of these at a time and in both of them in the same time. I tried to put the log4j.properties in the tomcat catalog.

I don't know if this is possible to do when you're using maven. Anyone who knows and can help?

Comment: The file whould be packaged into the war file you are using so how could that file being overwritten ? And why do you change the resource configuration ? Keep the conventions....

Comment: what do you mean by - log4j.properties-file will be overwritten?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390521/change-location-of-log4j-properties

Comment: What I mean with overwritten is that my log4j.properties file after a deploy is in the folder C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\myWebap\WEB-INF\classes. 
If I would change the log4j.properties in this folder, and then later on would make a change in my code and make a new deploy the log4j.properties would be replaced with the version that is in eclipse. 
I might want to have different log4j.properties files in different machines.

Answer (score 2):

From the Log4j 2 documentation:

> ```
> Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and, if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension.
> If no system property is set the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.properties in the classpath.
> If no such file is found the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.yaml or log4j2-test.yml in the classpath.
> If no such file is found the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.json or log4j2-test.jsn in the classpath.
> If no such file is found the XML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2-test.xml in the classpath.
> If a test file cannot be located the properties ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.properties on the classpath.
> If a properties file cannot be located the YAML ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.yaml or log4j2.yml on the classpath.
> If a YAML file cannot be located the JSON ConfigurationFactory will look for log4j2.json or log4j2.jsn on the classpath.
> If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.
> If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.
> ```

So you should be able to set the "log4j.configurationFile" property when you start tomcat to the location of your config file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with regard to log4j/logback/etc

If you are using 'log4j.properties'. You can specify a -D (via a setenv.bat/sh file in %CATALINA_BASE%\bin or ${CATALINA_BASE}/bin respectively).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2389515/289625) for some more detail on the format.

However, with log4j2 you can use the [XInclude](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XInclude) syntax if you switch to an XML format. By doing so, you can place your configuration in say ${catalina.base}/conf/log4j2-included.xml and your embedded log4j2 configuration would include that file.

Comment: How do I use log4j2 as xml? I've tried to use it as XML-format instead of a log4j.properties. However I don't get any log only the following error: 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.cgi.searcheditor.jerseyjackson.jaxrs.resource.MyClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.