# log4j not working in the first time

Tags: configuration, log4j

I am tring to implement log4j for the first time. My log4j.properties file is as given below.

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /log/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = debug, NewStudentListDAO

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/log/log4j/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

I have placed this file under classes folder and src folder. Still it does not give out to file. The log4j is invoked in my class `NewStudentListDAO` in the following lines. The site is not allowing me to submit this much alone so I am adding some special characters to fill the gap. Kindly ignore the same...

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( NewStudentListDAO.class.getName());
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
logger.debug("This is debug message from logger");
logger.info("This is info message from logger");
logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "This is a debug message from logger");
```

Kindly help me in fixing the issue.

Thanks 
Saji

Comment: It works fine for console appender which is given as below
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /log/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = ALL, A1
log4j.logger.NewStudentListDAO=INFO, NewStudentListDAO

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.NewStudentListDAO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.NewStudentListDAO.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

Answer (score 0):

Try this adding to your logger file, and check whether it is first displaying on your console.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

Look at this link

[Log4j: How to configure simplest possible file logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358836/log4j-how-to-configure-simplest-possible-file-logging).

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have tested, the console logger is working fine but the file appender does not work fine.The log4j.properties file is as given below.

log4j.rootLogger = ALL, com.rams.common.RootLogger
log4j.logger.NewStudentListDAO=DEBUG, com.rams.DAO.report.NewStudentListDAO

log4j.appender.rootLogger=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.rootLogger.File=/log/log4j/log.out
log4j.appender.rootLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rootLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

#Rest in my next comment

Comment: log4j.appender.NewStudentListDAO=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.NewStudentListDAO.File=/log/log4j/log.out
log4j.appender.NewStudentListDAO.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.NewStudentListDAO.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n