# Can i have 2 separate log files for the same class using log4j?

Tags: java, logging

I have a class in which i am using log4j to log messages. I have log messages in if and else part of the code. I need to log the messages in if{} condition to a separate log file and  the else part log messages to a separate log file. For example in the below code the message inside if should be logged in log1 file and inside else message should be logged in log2 file. I am using log4J XML configuration file.  May i know if this is possible using log4j?? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
if(id=1){
logger.info("inside if");
}else{
logger.info("inside else");
}
```

Comment: Two different loggers maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Just use/configure two `FileAppender`s with different file paths for your logger-path. Every logger can have more than one appender. This [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358836/log4j-how-to-configure-simplest-possible-file-logging) contains an example how to do this (look there for multiple use of appender-ref-tag).

Answer (score 0):

Could you use two loggers? Something like this:

```
Logger loggerIf = Logger.getLogger("com.foo.MyClass.if");
Logger loggerElse = Logger.getLogger("com.foo.MyClass.else");
if (id == 1) {
    loggerIf.info("inside if");
} else {
    loggerElse.info("inside else");
}
```

Then configure each logger to have a different appender, each pointing at a different file.

Comment: I doubt if system admins responsible for logging configuration will be happy if they find logger names not following package names but internal code details.