# Write log4j internal logging to file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is it possible to save the log4j **internal** debugging mentioned [here](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.co.il/2006/07/know-how-log4j-tries-to-configure.html) to file instead of just console?

Comment: Using "[log4j write to file](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&hl=pl&q=log4j%20write%20to%20file)" query on google I managed to find something like [how to write to a text file using to log4j?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474646/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-using-to-log4j), which also leads to [Log4j: How to configure simplest possible file logging?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6358836/1393766). Do they answer your question?

Comment: I don't want to write my logs to a file. I want the internal log4j debugger.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Anyway consider adding this information to your question for example for people (like me) which had never used log4j to prevent them from voting to close this question as duplicate of question similar to what I put in my earlier comment.