# How to disable Hibernate logs in Eclipse?

Tags: java, hibernate, model-view-controller

I am new to hibernate , I am doing project in Eclipse. When I log in to my application it displays to many log messages in console which I dont need, the log message is something like this,

```
97 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
102 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
103 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
105 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
108 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
165 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
165 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
220 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
262 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.aurodisplay.its.beans.UserRegisterBean
296 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.aurodisplay.its.beans.UserRegisterBean on table users
334 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.aurodisplay.its.beans.AdminInfoBean
334 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.aurodisplay.its.beans.AdminInfoBean on table admin_info
337 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.aurodisplay.its.beans.LatitudeBean
337 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.aurodisplay.its.beans.LatitudeBean on table latlng
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/its_serverdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
     // next are mappings
```

I have integrated Log4j , Here is my Log4j.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%c{1}] %-5p :%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/ITS_Server.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%c{1}] %-5p:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="org.hibernate">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
</category>

<category name="java.sql">
    <priority value="debug" />
</category>

<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="info"/> 
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />


  </root>

 </log4j:configuration>
```

How can I disable it. When I google about it, somany solutions are using `Log4j` I dont know what is it and what is it for. can I do disable logs without `Log4j` if possible please tell me how .It would be greate help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

set

```
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
```

When creating session use

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate");
    log.setLevel(Level.your_level);
```

This should stop the logging and you don't have to use any `xml` or `cfg` file

Comment: I am getting error `ERROR cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: sorry  @Raghu i forgot the exact level it is FATAL

Comment: when creating session means `SessionFactory sFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();` before this line?

Comment: No its not working , I did like this. `Logger log = Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate");
     log.setLevel(Level.OFF);
  SessionFactory sFactory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
   //Session session= HibernateSession.getHibernateSession();
  Session session= sFactory.openSession();`   FATAL level is not there

Comment: please just give this a try : `org.hibernate.SQL` instead of `org.hibernate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75499/discussion-between-raghu-and-saif).

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! I executed that piece of code, at the time of creating the session factory

Answer (score 1):

Try follwing lines in log4j.xml.

```
<Root> 
<Level value = "INFO" /> 
<Appender-ref ref = "console" /> 
<Appender-ref ref = "rootLogger" /> 
</Root>
```

I used following line in log4j.properties which worked for me.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, console
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=../logs/Log_report.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: can you please come for chat online . I want to discus about this.

Comment: Don't I need to define any category for hibernate logs

Comment: please look at my updated question , I have added my Log4j.xml file. please tell me what are the changes I have to make.

Comment: Did not define any and hibernate logs were not stored in the log.

Comment: I want to store all Hibernate logs in separate file , What I have to do in above xml.

Comment: Can you make the value "INFO" for <level value="DEBUG" /> and try?

Comment: No its not logging in there .

Comment: I used the log4j.properties, It worked fine. Read about the <root> but never tested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75793/discussion-between-raghu-and-saqib-rezwan).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

`log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info`

More info [Turning off hibernate logging console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output)

Comment: cant we do without `log4j`, or else  please tell me how to configure log4j for this

Answer (score 0):

As you dont have any logger, try adding this in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```
<!-- Limit the org.hibernate category to INFO since logging to DEBUG affects performance badly -->  
<category name="org.hibernate">  
    <priority value="WARN"/>  
</category>
```

o write your logging information into a file, when you have Log4j installed you would have to use **org.apache.log4j.FileAppender**.

Following is a sample configuration file log4j.properties for FileAppender −

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474646/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-using-to-log4j) for further info.

Comment: I am not using `Log4j` (I dont have any external jars related to `Log4j`). Then also will it work.

Comment: its giving error `org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration` and rootcause `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 54; columnNumber: 34; Element type "category" must be declared.`

Comment: Hello , I have integrated Log4j now, How can I log all Hibernate logs in to file.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but usefull :

First, you can use log4j configuration file (add this to your pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Finally, to disable logging, put in src/main/resources/log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
```

Comment: where in the log4j.properties should you add that?