# Log4j : Exclude Log from Console but create new log file for those logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j

My Java project contains following packages -
com.main.log4j.main , com.main.log4j.other.

I want log lines of package "com.main.log4j.other" to be removed from Console log, rather maintain a different log file for the same package. I am using Log4j version 1.2.16, with following log4j.xml config.

```
<appender name="CONSOLE-LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="..." />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="OTHER-LOG" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/Others.log" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="..." />
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="com.main.log4j.other">
    <appender-ref ref="OTHER-LOG" />
</category>
<root>
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE-LOG" />
</root>
```

Using this config, a separate log file Others.log is created with log line, but those log lines are still present in console log.
I want to exclude them.
Please suggest me how I can configure the log4j.xml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write to a text file using to log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474646/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-using-to-log4j)

Comment: @RaghavaDhanya 
Thanks for the reply, but my problem is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `additivity` to false in your "com.main.log4j.other" category :

```
<category name="com.main.log4j.other" additivity="false">
```

This will prevent those logs to be also logged in the root logger.

Comment: Posted a new Problem statement - 
How to resolve Warning : Unrecognized element - rollingPolicy , triggeringPolicy?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805122/log4j-how-to-resolve-warning-unrecognized-element-rollingpolicy-triggeri

Comment: Can we achieve the following ? 
1. I want FATAL level logs of package "com.main.log4j.other" will remain the part of Console log.
2. Only DEBUG & INFO level Log lines of package "com.main.log4j.other" will be part of "Others.log".
Is there any way to do both of this?

NB: Part 2 - can be achieved by using LevelMatchFilter and DenyAllFilter.