Cannot add Log to file in jersey project
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'
                   >

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <param name="file" value="D:/download/vuquanganh/logging.log"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project_jdbc_jersey</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project_jdbc_jersey</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>project_jdbc_jersey</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <version>19.13.0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add Log4j dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>4.0.0-M1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <war.mvn.plugin.version>3.4.0</war.mvn.plugin.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

    </properties>
</project>

@Path("/todo")
public class TodoResource {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TodoResource.class.getName());

    TodoService todoService=new TodoService();
    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getList() {
        List<TodoEntity> todoEntityList = todoService.getTodoEntityList();
        DOMConfigurator.configure("D:\\download\\vuquanganh\\project_jdbc_jersey\\src\\main\\resources\\log4j2.xml");
        log.info("Lấy thông tin về ToDoList");
        return todoEntityList.toString();
    }

Kết nối thành công
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [DEBUG].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [append] to [false].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [10MB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [D:/download/vuquanganh/logging.log].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: D:/download/vuquanganh/logging.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Adding appender named [file] to category [root].
08-Apr-2024 09:56:50.062 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.example.resources.TodoResource.getList Lấy thông tin về ToDoList
I am trying to write log to a file but it only outputs to the console and cannot be exported to a file. I am sure the path to the file is correct.


Hello, it seems you are using log4j 1.2 but not log4j 2, I'm not familiar with the XML config, but you may try the logo4j.properties file described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474646/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-using-to-log4j to see if it helps. Also, there is log4j2 XML samples in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206993/very-simple-log4j2-xml-configuration-file-using-console-and-file-appender
